# Can't create dynamic IonIcons in ionic-react project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, ionicons, ionic-react

i am using many components in my project and in all those components need different different ionIcon for each component. So i created Icon component. Icon name passed from each parent components to the Icon child component. But its not validating.

**

```
<Icon name="closeCircleOutline" /> \\ this is the parent component
```

> Icon Component

```
import { IonIcon, IonItem } from "@ionic/react";
 import * as iconName from "ionicons/icons";
export default function Icon(props: any) { 
var propsIcon = props.name; // icon name passed from parent component
return <IonIcon icon={iconName.propsIcon}></IonIcon>; 
}
```

> Property 'propsIcon' does not exist on type 'typeof
> import("/Users/dubaitradeit/Desktop/Mobile
> Apps/Ionic/lastMile/node_modules/ionicons/icons/index")' 
> the above warning iam getting

Comment: You should import it, where you use it, otherwise it cant find, my suggestion is that find dynamic importing ionicon library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to write the below code

```
return <IonIcon icon={iconName.props}></IonIcon>;
```

Instead of referring to 'props' you referred to 'propsIcon' which is not-existent in icons library. Hope this rectifies your issue.